# Side loading certificate

Tags: windows-10-universal

How do I make the warning go away that my app is unsafe to install when side loading?

Do I have to create a certificate? This app is never intended to be released in the Windows Store. I read on MSDN that there is a *test certificate* shipped with every VS project, so not sure why this warning exists.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make the warning go away that my app is unsafe to install when side loading?

I think there is no way to make it go away.

> Do I have to create a certificate?

Yes, otherwise it will fail when you package your UWP apps. And if the certificate is not installed on your device, your app cannot be installed in sideload mode.

> so not sure why this warning exists.

Because our test certificate is not a microsoft trusted certificate, certification is used for recognizing the developer of this app, for sideload, we only need a self-trusted certificate or a business uniform pfx.

**Update:** Where to choose the certificate:

[image]

Comment: Like I said, this app is not intended to be published to the Store - what do I have to do to certify it offline?

Comment: What does the `Launch Certification Kit` do when you package an app? Is this what I need to make the app easier to sideload?

Comment: @Alexej, this is a safety mechanism for installing UWP apps, we can only install an app with trusted certificate, no matter it is a self-trusted (Popup dialog will show to tell you this is not safe), a store certificate or a microsoft trusted certificate.

Comment: I see. May I ask again how to do the self-trusted certificate? Is this what the `Launch Certification Kit` option is for?

Comment: @Alexej, when you package the app, you can firstly change the certificate by clicking the `Choose Certificate...` button in appxmanifest as you can see it from the image I updated in my answer. If you don't need to change it, then it is by default a self-trusted certificate. And I'm not quite understand with your `Launch Certification Kit` option, where is this option?

Comment: Oh I think it's an option after you build the appx packages (but maybe only for the Store, so not really what I'm after). So I can use `Choose Certificate...` and set it to the test certificate to make it easier for people to sideload?

Comment: @Alexej, it depends on what is your test certificate, if it is a microsoft trusted certificate, the unsafe warning will not be shown, but is this can make it easier for people to sideload? I have to say, a .cer file for your app must be installed firstly before installing your app.